# Skinning a Button component in pure AS3 / Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to "skin" my Flash application's buttons using either ActionScript or Flash Professional, without having to rely on Flex code or libraries.

Right now my buttons have no skins at all, though there is black text where the label is, so I know they're there.

I've tried using the getStyle and setStyle methods, but can't get them to work.

How do I link a button to a PNG image to skin it in Flash?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your own button using mouse events for functionality, color transformations for appearance states, etc. in AS3.

or you can simply use the stock button component and edit its appearance in Flash Authoring (CS5).  to edit your stock components in Flash Authoring, just double click on the component in the library (once you've added it to your project) to see/edit its states.